# How to redirect a Flask application with Nginx and uWSGI?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, deployment, uwsgi

When the user enters the url http://localhost:8000/Hello, I need to redirect him to http://localhost:8081/Hello.

Here is my attempt on the deploy.conf file:

```
server {
  listen 8000;

  location /Hello { 
    include uwsgi_params; 
    uwsgi_pass localhost:8081/Hello; 
    }
  }
```

But when I check nginx with: sudo nginx -t

I get this error:
nginx: [emerg] invalid host in upstream "localhost:8081/Hello" in /projects/challenge/deploy.conf

Please any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to the improper format of the `uwsgi_pass` directive. The `uwsgi_pass` directive expects a URL or a Unix socket path as its argument, not a complete URL with a path.

Try this way:

```
server {
    listen 8000;

    location /Hello {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass localhost:8081;  # Use only the base URL
    }
}
```

In this configuration, you're instructing Nginx to proxy requests that match the `/Hello` path to the uWSGI server running on `localhost:8081`.

Keep in mind that this Nginx configuration assumes that your uWSGI server is properly configured and running on `localhost:8081`.

After making this change, you should reload Nginx for the changes to take effect:

```bash
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

the uwsgi_pass should point to the uswgi server so your config file would look like this:

```
server {
  listen 8000;

  location /Hello { 
    include uwsgi_params; 
    uwsgi_pass localhost:8081; 
    }
  }
```